# Enumeration missing from Cocoa Touch Calendaring classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nscalendar

After a few hours of working with `NSCalendar`, `NSDate` and `NSDateComponents`, it occurred to me that Apple did not create an enumeration for weekdays.

Apparently, judging by the framework, all world is using the 7 days in a week approach to week days..and those week days have names that are universal in meaning i.e. a translated Sunday to for example hungarian is a different word (Vasarnap) but it MEANS Sunday. I speak hungarian + 4 other languages besides english so I know for sure.

If we extract the `NSCalendarUnitWeekDay` component, we can quickly find out that it returns `NSInteger`, and Sunday is represented by 1, Monday is 2, etc..

It is very easy to extend `NSCalendar` to provide such enumeration and I already did that actually and so far it turns out to be practical.
But I am wondering perhaps I am missing something and there is a reason for omitting such enumeration.

Is there?

Comment: Why is an enumeration needed? What of differences in first day of the week? How about calendars such as the Jewish calendar where a day starts at sundown? Conceptually, a calendar need not have 7 day weeks. I've thought of creating a 14 day week calendar for the purpose of setting fortnightly reminders. Just some thoughts....

Comment: Because when you inspect the NSDateComponents.weekday property, it returns an integer and you don't know what that number means. Same goes for firstDayOfTheWeek property.

Answer (score 0):

There is not. It does seem strange but the only reason I can think of for not including an enum is that due to localization, the "meaning" of the 1, 2, 3, etc would change and by defining an enum for the Gregorian calendar, this would lead to an implied assumption that Sunday=1 which is *only* correct some calendars.